# how to change thousands separator for blank in R plotly?

Tags: r, graphics, plotly

I would like to change the big number separator from comma to blank in plotly. I can do this in ggplot2, but not in plotly. It should probably be done through tickformat option (https://plotly.com/r/reference/#layout-xaxis-tickformat), but after trying some d3-format as specified here : https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md I don't get it.

For exemple, in the following graph :

```
diamonds %>%
plot_ly(x=~clarity,y=~~depth*10000) %>%
add_bars()
```

I don't want to have "50K", "40K" on the y axis, but "50 000", "40 000".

If I add

```
layout(yaxis=list(tickformat=","))
```

I get "50,000", "40,000" ...

If I add

```
layout(yaxis=list(tickformat=" "))
```

I get "50000","40000"...

But I can't get a blank space separator.

```
layout(yaxis=list(tickformat=","))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach formating labels and text with `tickvals` and `ticktext` in `layout`. You can create your breaks with a sequence and then formating it to have the desired outcome. Here the code:

```
library(plotly)
#Labels
ticklabels <- seq(from=0, to=round(max(diamonds$depth*10000)), by=10000)
ticktexts <- c(0,paste(ticklabels[-1]/1000, " 000", sep=""))
#Code
diamonds %>%
  plot_ly(x=~clarity,y=~~depth*10000) %>%
  add_bars() %>%
  layout(yaxis=list(tickvals = ticklabels,
                    ticktext = ticktexts
                    ))
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the `tickformat` option together with `separators` one may get the blank big number separator automatically, without needing to externally specify both breaks and labels:

```
library(plotly)

diamonds %>%
  plot_ly(x=~clarity,y=~~depth*10000) %>%
  add_bars() %>% 
  layout(yaxis = list(tickformat = ",.", hoverformat = ",."), separators = ". ")
```

where, additionally, the hoverformat has been specified in the same way as the tickformat. Remark that in the `separators` string the dot accounts for the decimal marker and the blank space afterwards stands for the thousands separator.

Other notations may be obtained this way, e. g. the French "dot-comma" (42.345,78 for 42345.78) would require `separators = ",."`.